# How to find the number of occurrences of sub-strings in another string in BigQuery with conditionals as a cumulative sum?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum

So my SQL/BiqQuery skills still need some refining and I have been stuck on this for some time now. I got a table ST that marks the planned mods to some applications with their starting date, these mods only apply to those with some specific specs:

| Mod_ID | App_ID | Specs | Start_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | App1 | S1 | 2022-01-24 |
| P1 | App2 | S2 | 2022-01-24 |
| P2 | App2 | S3 S4 | 2022-03-15 |
| P3 | App3 | S4 S5 | 2022-04-10 |

I got another table AQ that includes the production date for some devices, with their corresponding app and their specifications in the form of a string:

| Device_ID | App_ID | Spec_string | Prod_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID0001 | App1 | S1 S4 S6 T0 U7 | 2022-02-03 |
| ID0002 | App2 | S2 S5 U9 | 2022-02-05 |
| ID0003 | App2 | S1 S2 S3 | 2022-03-12 |
| ID0004 | App3 | S5 S6 T0 U7 | 2022-04-18 |

I want to count the occurrences of the different spec mods for a particuar device that apply to its App_ID and only for those that AQ.Prod_Date>=ST.Start_Date.

I first unnested table ST (ST_UNN) and ended with something like this:

| Mod_ID | App_ID | Specs_ind | Start_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | App1 | S1 | 2022-01-24 |
| P1 | App2 | S2 | 2022-01-24 |
| P2 | App2 | S3 | 2022-03-15 |
| P2 | App2 | S4 | 2022-03-15 |
| P3 | App3 | S4 | 2022-04-10 |
| P3 | App3 | S5 | 2022-04-10 |

and tried the following:

```
SELECT
  a.* EXCEPT(Spec_String),
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.App_ID = a.App_ID AND s.Start_Date <= a.Prod_Date THEN ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Spec_String, Specs_ind))
    ELSE
    0
  END
    ) OVER(PARTITION BY s.Specs_ind ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS num_changes,
FROM
  AQ AS a
LEFT JOIN
  ST_UNN AS s
ON
  a.App_ID  = s.App_ID
```

But it didn't work as intended. I expect something like this:

| Device_ID | App_ID | Spec_string | Prod_Date | num_changes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID0001 | App1 | S1 S4 S6 T0 U7 | 2022-02-03 | 1 |
| ID0002 | App2 | S2 S5 U9 | 2022-02-05 | 1 |
| ID0003 | App2 | S1 S3 U7 | 2022-03-12 | 0 |
| ID0004 | App3 | S5 S6 T0 U7 | 2022-04-18 | 1 |

But I am rather lost on how to achieve this last part as a cumulative sum, so that a device will count all mod implementations that have happened before its production date and that apply based on its specifications.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, you can simplify a little and just group by device_id, etc. instead of using a window function. I modified your input slightly just to show that this was working as intended

```sql
WITH
  st AS (
  SELECT
    'P1' AS mod_id,
    'App1' AS app_id,
    'S1 S4' AS specs,
    '2022-01-24' AS start_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'P1',
    'App2',
    'S2',
    '2022-01-24'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'P2',
    'App2',
    'S3 S4',
    '2022-03-15'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'P3',
    'App3',
    'S4 S5',
    '2022-04-10'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'P4',
    'App3',
    'S4 S5',
    '2022-04-11' ),
  st_unn AS (
  SELECT
    * EXCEPT(specs)
  FROM
    st,
    UNNEST(SPLIT(specs, ' ')) AS spec ),
  aq AS (
  SELECT
    -- should be 2
    'ID0001' AS device_id,
    'App1' AS app_id,
    'S1 S4 S6 T0 U7' AS spec_string,
    '2022-02-03' AS prod_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    -- should be 1
    'ID0002',
    'App2',
    'S2 S5 U9',
    '2022-02-05'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
  -- should be 0
    'ID0003',
    'App2',
    'S2 S5 U9',
    '2021-03-12'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    -- should be 3
    'ID0004',
    'App3',
    'S4 S5 S6 T0 U7',
    '2022-04-18' )
SELECT
  device_id,
  aq.app_id,
  spec_string,
  prod_date,
  SUM(COALESCE(ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(spec_string, spec)), 0))
FROM
  aq
LEFT JOIN
  st_unn st
ON
  aq.prod_date >= st.start_date
  AND aq.app_id = st.app_id
GROUP BY
  device_id,
  aq.app_id,
  spec_string,
  prod_date
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to +1 your answer, but this works wonders.  The only "but" is that I couldn't run the query since it wouldn't allow me to use GROUP BY with prod_date, but I just omitted it and kept the rest.